# Postman - send POST request multiple times, however with different values in the body

Tags: postman

I am relatively new to Postman.

I need to send POST request:

```
\\\
    {
      "name": "{{newGroupTypeToCreate}}"
    }
\\\
```

in example two times (two iterations) and for each iteration to have name to be different.

I created global variable newGroupTypeList in the Environment (with no value),

[image]

also, I created another two variables in the environment: "newGroupTypeToCreate" and "newGroupTypeToCreateToDelete" this time with values assigned to them.
So, in Pre-Request I create 2 locals for each of them:

```
\\\
// create local variables from the Environment variables
var locCreatedNewUsrGrType = pm.environment.get("newGroupTypeToCreate");
var locCreatedNewUsrGrTypeToDelete = pm.environment.get("newGroupTypeToCreateToDelete");
\\\
```

and then I create another local variable (the third one) which will be an array of two variables mentioned:

```
\\\
// initialize local variable list to have values from the local variables:
var locNewUsrGroupTypesList = [locCreatedNewUsrGrType, locCreatedNewUsrGrTypeToDelete]
\\\
```

Then I just set Global variable newGroupTypeList (mentioned above) to be equal to the local variable locNewUsrGroupTypesList.

```
\\\
// set environment variable to contain the list of the variables
    pm.environment.set("newGroupTypeList", locNewUsrGroupTypesList)
\\\
```

[image]

I assigned the value of the locNewUsrGroupTypesList to the Global variable newGroupTypeList, so I can use it in the body to send requests for the first and the second value in the list/array.  Remember, that newGroupTypeList is a list of two elements (see the screenshot of the console.log):

[image]

And at that point I am stuck, I do not know how to make Postman to send newGroupTypeList[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtaRf.png) firstly and then newGroupTypeList[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukfml.png).

I know that I may use something like setNextRequest method:

```
\\\
    postman.setNextRequest("{{baseUrl}}/api/UserGroupTypes");
\\\
```

But I do not understand how to make it work with each index/element of newGroupTypeList.
I also know there is a way to create CSV file and define values there, but I prefer firstly to try to do it like I have started already, if this is possible, of course.

Need your kind advice, Team.